# StringBuilder functionality issue

Tags: string, builder

```
private ResponseDTO SyncPODetails(PODTO po)
        {
            //TODO Take string builder here and  append values from loop to this string builder 
            string query = "";
            try
            {
                query = "insert into " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbUser"] + ".PODetail(WHSEID,POKEY,POLINENUMBER,STORERKEY,SKU,SKUDESCRIPTION,QTYORDERED,QTYADJUSTED,QTYRECEIVED,PACKKEY,UNITPRICE,UOM,EFFECTIVEDATE,FORTE_FLAG,ITEM_NUMBER,SKU_WGT,SKU_CUBE,SKU_HGT,UNIT_COST,UNIT_SHIP,SUSR1,SUSR2,QTYREJECTED,STATUS,QCAUTOADJUST,QCREQUIRED,ADDDATE,ADDWHO,EDITDATE,EDITWHO,ITEMPRICEREF,POPLANID,LOADPLANQTY,ORDERKEY,ORDERLINENUMBER,ASSIGNEDQTY,SUPPLIERRECEIVEDQTY,SUPPLIERRECEIPTDATE,QTYPOPULATED,ORDEREDQTY)"
          + " values('LMRWHS1','{0}','{1}','KGL','{2}','{3}',{4},0.00,0.00,'{5}',{6},'{7}','{8}','I',0,{9},{10},0.00,{11},0.00,'{12}','{13}',0.00,0,0,0,'{14}','{15}','{16}','{17}','{18}','{19}',0.00,'{20}','{21}',0.00,0.00,'{22}',0.00,0.00);";

                //ar n = "";
                foreach (var pd in po.POdetails)
                {
                    n = n + pd.NSN;
                    //TODO:remove the query here and keep it out of loop i.e before the loop 
                    //TODO: Remove this select is not required 
                   //query= query + "select max(SERIALKEY) SERIALKEY from " + ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["dbUser"] + ".PODetail";
                    query = string.Format(query,
                        po.POKey,
                        pd.POLineNumber,
                        pd.NSN,
                        pd.NSNDescription,
                        pd.OpenQuantity,//pd.PalletQuantities.Sum(x => x.PalletQuantity),
                        "STD",
                        pd.UnitPrice,
                        pd.UOM,
                        po.CreatedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"),
                        pd.STDGROSSWGT,
                        "0",
                        pd.UnitPrice,
                       pd.AgreementRefNo,
                        "DRY",
                        po.CreatedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"),
                        pd.CreatedByName,
                        po.UpdatedDate.Year < 1990 ? null : po.UpdatedDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy hh:mm:ss tt"),
                        pd.UpdatedByName,
                        pd.ITEMPRICEREF,
                        po.PlanNo,
                        pd.WMSOrderKey,
                        pd.CustomerOrderLineNo,
                        po.VendorDeliveryDate.ToString("MM-dd-yyyy")
                        );
                    LogHelper.LogInfo(query);
                    // TODO: Remove this 
                    var result = ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectionStringCPRD, query);
                }
                LogHelper.LogInfo(n);
                //TODO: Execute the string builder here like this ExecuteNonQuery(ConnectionStringCPRD, query);  
                return new ResponseDTO { Status = true, Message = "PO  Synced sucessfully", SingleResponse = po.Id };
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                RevereseSync(po);
                LogHelper.LogError("Sync PO Details" + query, ex);
                return new ResponseDTO { Status = false, Message = "PO  not synced sucessfully", SingleResponse = po.Id };
            }
        }
```

Comment: Actually iam aklready write commit in code

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow. What is your functionality issue? What error are you seeing? Could you reduce the amount of code to just the problem?

Comment: Actually please use to string builder and query state ment also above of the foreach loop how to pass to Take string builder here and  append values from loop to this string builder

Comment: 1) Please ask an actual question rather than just post code, 2) please post the code so that it is correctly formatted (the question edit box has a tool for that) and 3) please put the appropriate language tag for this (`c#`?). `builder` is not an appropriate tag since that tag is for a design pattern.

Comment: Actually my questions is -- Please write Take string builder here and  append values from loop to this string builder

Comment: That isn't a question, it is a request. Furthermore it is under-specified. Please edit your question so that it has text and not just code. The text should clearly explain what your problem is. Are you asking how string builders work?

Comment: Actually not working please write using stringBuilder

Comment: Stack Overflow is a question/answer site, where specific questions are asked and answered. It is not a free coding service, which you seem to be trying to use it as.